# Integrate Amazon Cognito with JFrog Artifactory

Tags: amazon-cognito, artifactory

I would like to enable SAML based auth in JFrog artifactory using Amazon Cognito

Here is what I have done on the AWS side of things

We use SSO to login to our Amazon accounts. Under IAM identity center -> Applications, I have created a SAML 2.0 application and added a few users to it. This is my primary iDP.

Now in Cognito, I went ahead and created a user pool. The Federated identity provider for this pool is the iDP provider I created above (SAML based). Under App Inegration, I went ahead and created a test app and its config looks like this

[image]

Now on the Artifactory side, I login as admin --> Settings --> Authentication Providers --> OAuth SSO --> New Provider. I choose Provider Type to be OpenID and it asks me the following

[image]

Im aware of the clientID and secret but Im trying to understand how to get the rest. Is [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html) the authorization endpoint I need to use ? What would my domain be in this ?

Is it even possible to use AWS Cognito with JFrog Artifactory this way?